# cannot ping link-local address from other subnet when defaut gateway route is seted

Tags: linux, networking, debian, avahi, bonjour

I have a problem with my route table I don't know why it doesn't work.

I have two test cases, I did draw a network map for each case.

**currently I can't resolv the goal**.

[image: testcase-1 network map]

[image: testcase-2 network map]

> The goal:

1. laptop-1 can ping raspberry pi **over zeroconf ip**
2. laptop-2 can ping raspberry pi **over zeroconf ip**
3. raspberry pi can ping 8.8.8.8 **over the default route**

> testcase-1

**the default gateway on raspberry pi's eth0 is 192.168.15.180**

- Laptop-1 can ping raspi
- Laptop-2 cannot ping raspi
- raspi can ping 8.8.8.8

  Routing table

  ```
  default via 192.168.15.180 dev eth0
  default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.218.78
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.6
  ```

> testcase-2

**no default gateway on raspberry pi's eth0**

- Laptop-1 can ping raspi
- Laptop-2 can ping raspi
- raspi cant ping 8.8.8.8

  Routing table

  ```
  default dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.218.78
  169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
  192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.6
  ```

I hope anybody can help me.
Thanks guys

Comment: Ok so we can probably discount testcase-2 (no default gateway = no WAN ping). testcase-1 is interesting. Can you take a packet capture on the raspberry pi's eth0 interface and see if the ICMP requests are being received? If not, you can narrow down your investigation to either the switch or laptop.

Comment: yeah testcase-2 is only to see that zeroconf work from other subnet when on raspi no default gw is seted. laptop and switch are ok while otherwise testcase-2 doesnt work. also i testet this in a virtual box with fresh ubuntu 16.04, and i have the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Your Firewall does not seem to know about the network 192.168.1.6 is in icmp redirects are not accepted.

Try adding a route to 192.168.1.0/24 (presumably) dev eth0 on raspi which should make testcase-1 work for you. `ip ro add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0`

Comment: i ping the raspberry pi over the zeroconf ip and not with the 192.168.1.6 address, like ip cameras (axis) there have often a link local address to configure the device when is this in a other subnet. thank you

Comment: Alright, then this is a layer 2 issue. check ARP (ip neigh ls) resolution on all sides. On that note, have you powercycled the switch yet?

Comment: i have check both arp tables and are ok, yes a try all this stuf =), i work with avahi-autpid i dont know why this out of the box not work for me when i have set the default route on raspi. mabye a flag in ipv4 settings or similar i dont know.